# Alter table nvarchar(100) to nvarchar(150) in production environment in a table with 20 million rows

Tags: sql-server

I should change the nvarchar size from 100 to 150 in my production table. This is a huge table in a production environment (over 20 million rows) with continuous read and write. Are there any best practices to do that safely (without locking table)?

Comment: It may help you: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/15008

Answer (score 1):

Provided you are not changing the nullability (`null` > `not null` or vice versa), this is basically an instant change to the table meta data; ensure you include the existing column's `null` state in the alter statement.

The operation will need to aquire a *schema stability lock* to make the change so be aware this itself may briefly cause blocking of other queries against the table, however the operation itself is quick.